# React Native - what is the difference between bundle-output and assets-dest?

Tags: android, react-native

According to the docs, the command to create release build in Android Studio is:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/res/
```

As I understand, the release APK uses index.android.bundle file generated in `/assets` folder to load the React View. Also I understand that `--bundle-output android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` generates it. But what `--assets-dest android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/res/`
Is used for?
I am trying to create an app that dynamically receives index.android.bundle from a server and I wonder if the app should receive something else except of the bundle file to load the React View successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This option (`--assets-dest`) tells the bundler the location of where you want to copy over all the assets of your project (ie. images/fonts etc..)

Comment: So what if i want to create the bundle somewhere else (when RN and Android folder are completely separated, maybe even on different machines)? I hoped that I could just provide the index.android.bundle file to make RN work on release apk.

Comment: The bundle file should be inside the application directory. So if you can see the `--bundle-output`and the `--assets-dest` both are pointing to the application directory but in a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

`— bundle-output=` Is the path where `main.bundlejs` will be created.

`--assets-dest` Tells the bundler the destination to copy all the assets to (in this case just images).

Comment: So what if i want to create the bundle somewhere else (when RN and Android folder are completely separated, maybe even on different machines)? I hoped that I could just provide the index.android.bundle file to make RN work on release apk.

Comment: what is the default for `--assets-dest` ?